# Автоматический запуск проекта при запуске Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Как заставить среду программирования Eclipse Java запускать определённый проект сразу при её запуске? У меня всего создано несколько проектов. Я хочу, чтобы при запуске этой среды программирования начиналось выполнение определённого проекта.

Дело в том, что этот проект является веб-сервером. Система (компьютер с Windows 10) очень часто перезагружается в связи с перебоями с электричеством. Система сама после загрузки автоматически запускает Eclipse.

Каждый раз компилировать проект в `Runnable JAR File`... - не решение проблемы.

Comment: Если это веб-сервер, то может лучше запускать сам проект самостоятельно, чем через эклипс?

Comment: @Эникейщик, нет